# two banners not displaying separately in joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to display two banners at separate positions in joomla 1.7 using template beez_20 which comes with the installation but both of he banners are appearing at the same position. How can I separate them. I've set the position to position-3 and to position-5 both the banners are showing on both positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have two instances of the banners module - one published in the first position, another in the second position.  From the Modules Manager, copy the one you have, and make the changes to each accordingly

Comment: It's been awhile since i've used that module, but as i recall, what I had to do, was set one up for 1 client/category, and another client/category for the the 2nd, then they were separated.

Answer (score 0):

First upgrade to Joomla 2.5! 1.7 is not supported!

Comment: upgraded to 2.5 still banners in same place